# Barcode Scanner - Cordova Plugin

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, barcode-scanner

I have used the PhoneGap Plugin Barcode Scanner in an Android app. The functions `window.plugins.barcodeScanner.encode` and `window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan` work perfectly fine when I attach them to onclick events on buttons.

However, when I try to execute an encode function on an onload event of body/page init/page show event, I get the following error in Eclipse

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'encode' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/indexx.html:32
```

Thank you..

Answer (score 2):

Which version of phonegap are you using? 1.9.0 or 2.0.0?

2.0.0 has new methods of invoking plugins. 
on [1.9](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BarcodeScanner/), you would use:

```
window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan( function(result) {
    ...
    ..
}
```

If you are using 2.0.0, try a different way of initializing the plugin:

```
window.barcodeScanner = new BarcodeScanner();

function scanBarcode()
{
    window.barcodeScanner.scan(function(result) {
        alert("We got a barcode\n" +
              "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
              "Format: " + result.format); 
    }, function(error) {
        alert("Error scanning Barcode: " + error);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call the method once Cordova has finished loading (deviceready event)

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Cordova, but based on what I have seen it does sound like @traumalles is correct. To call the window.plugins.barcodeScanner.encode or window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan functions after Cordova has finished loading, do the following in your javascript file:

```
// Wait for Cordova to load
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Cordova is ready
function onDeviceReady() {
  // As an example, you now have the device name, Cordova version, etc. available
  alert('Device Name: ' + device.name);
  alert('Device Cordova: ' + device.cordova);
  alert('Device Platform: ' + device.platform);
  alert('Device UUID: ' + device.uuid);
  alert('Device Version: ' + device.version);

  // Now call one of your barcode functions, etc.
}
```

See http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#Device for more information.